# Query optimisation: Select min of a result set where a column is max of another set

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am trying to optimise my query and have got a little stuck.

Please consider the following table structure. I have also included some SQL in case you wish to build the table yourself:

```
| id | test_run_id | test_case_id |  test_step_id | test_result |
|----|-------------|--------------|---------------|-------------|
| 1  |      1      |       3      |      1        |      1      |
| 2  |      1      |       3      |      2        |      1      |
| 3  |      1      |       3      |      3        |      0      |
| 4  |      2      |       3      |      1        |      1      |
| 5  |      2      |       3      |      2        |      1      |
| 6  |      2      |       3      |      3        |      1      |

CREATE TABLE test_results(
    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    test_run_id INT(10) DEFAULT 0,
    test_case_id INT(10) DEFAULT 0,
    test_step_id INT(10) DEFAULT 0,
    test_result  CHAR(1) DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO test_results(
    `test_run_id`,
    `test_case_id`,
    `test_step_id`,
    `test_result`
) VALUES (
    1,
    3,
    1,
    1
), (
    1,
    3,
    2,
    1
), (
    1,
    3,
    3,
    0
), (
    2,
    3,
    1,
    1
), (
    2,
    3,
    2,
    1
), (
    2,
    3,
    3,
    1
);
```

Now, I want to get the most recent set of results as part of my query. And I know I could do that like this:

```
SELECT
    MIN( test_result ) as 'last_run_lowest'
FROM test_run_results
WHERE test_case_id=tc.id
AND test_run_id=(
    SELECT
        MAX( test_run_id )
    FROM test_run_results
    WHERE test_case_id=tc.id
)
```

And that would return me a single row:

```
| last_run_lowest |
|-----------------|
|       1         |
```

Which is what I want to do, as the value `1` means the last test run passed. However, doing things this way is taking up quite some time because of the amount of results in my `test_run_results` table.

What I would like to find out, is if there is a more efficient way to return the same data, so that the query does not take such a long time to run.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm confused. Given the accepted answer, why the MySQL tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just do it this way, if you only need the single value?

SQL Server version:

```
Select Top 1 test_result
from test_results
order by Test_run_ID desc, test_result asc
```

Per comments, MySQL version:

```
Select test_result
from test_results
order by Test_run_ID desc, test_result asc
limit 1;
```

Comment: And ensure the table has an appropriate index that matches the order by clause ;)

Comment: Thanks for this! My query is much faster now.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: How can this possibly be accepted on question (apparently correctly) tagged MySQL?  This code does not work in MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The MySQL tag was added by an edit after the question was posted - possible a mistake?

Comment: @APH . . . I don't think so.  The code in the question is not SQL Server.

Comment: I had to alter the code to work to the MySql server equivalent, but this got me started enough.